# Kill NPC's in NG+

Tags: dark-souls

I'm about to go in NG+ and I want to know if killing all the NPC's (especially Fire-keepers) has any downside? Do all the NPC's respawn in NG+? Don't they?

Apologies my poor English, I'm German!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no downside to killing the NPCs right before starting NG+, and [they will respawn](http://darksouls.wiki.fextralife.com/New+Game+Plus).

Normally, when you kill NPCs, you lose any services they provide (such as stores, or bonfires), as well as gaining "sin". However, all of this is reset once you enter NG+.